a function returning a dereferenced pointer has type reference?
In the code repository I am working on, I found the following function:
const Type & (int n)
{
...
return *this;
}

A dereferenced pointer of type * Type has type Type. How can this function have const Type & as signature?

the derefence operator returns a reference, not a copy

As you can see here operator* (AKA the indirection operator) returns a reference.

The return type of a function is governed by its specified return type in the function declaration irrespective of the operand of the return statement.

Is it wrong to dereference a pointer to get a reference? and see the 4 cases in C++ Returning Pointers/References

Why do you think it cannot have this signature?  It is totally common C++. *this should in principle always be valid (unless you access the object after deleting it).

@PepijnKramer I just don"t understand. The function returns a value, but the signature is a const reference. This is not the same thing.

"A dereferenced pointer of type * Type has type Type." -- This does not make sense. Suppose you had int *p initialized to some valid value. If *p returned int, then the expression *p = 3 would assign 3 to a copy of what p points to, not the object that p points to. Then again, a custom type could define the unary operator* to have any desired signature, but it is not recommended to do so.

https://godbolt.org/z/9fxPa9Gn9

@JaMiT your reply is way over my head - the only thing I know is: dereferencing a pointer gives the thing that the pointer points to. That thing is generally not a const reference, so why does this function return a const reference? Why is *this a const reference?

is this a pointer to a reference?

Loosely speaking here : Between the actual return statement and the return value an (implicit) conversion is allowed. E.g. char get_char() { int value = 1; return value; } should return an int because value is an int. But it is converted to a char because that's the signature for your function. The same why *this represents a valid instance of Type and that can be converted to a const Type&.  Returning a const& has some performance benefits so it is often used.

@Svalbard "dereferencing a pointer gives the thing that the pointer points to" -- Correct. It gives the thing, not a copy of the thing. In this phrasing, there is an implied reference because English has a different grammar than C++. A more precise phrasing would be "dereferencing a pointer gives a reference to the thing that the pointer points to". However, people find this overly wordy, redundant with the word "dereferencing", and somewhat obvious, so the phrase "a reference to" is often dropped outside beginners' textbooks.

All the damn advices in "smart" articles to use return type deduction and auto leads to questions like this :(
Analyze how the subscript operator works, and everything will become clear to you

@JaMiT it is not entirely obvious, it it? As far as I am concerned, dereferencing could be defined such that it returns the value of the object pointed to, and not a reference to it. But apparently this is not so.

@Svalbard "it is not entirely obvious" -- Correct. In fact, I often call out people who try to label something as "obvious", as that excuse is sorely overused. I do not intend to claim that the reasons for dropping the phrase are good/justified, only that those reasons exist, and they lead to the current reality. You can argue why things should not be the way they are, but that will not change the way they are. Maybe change the way they will be, but not the way they are.

*this produces a lvalue that identifies the object pointed to by this but it is not a reference. That lvalue is then used to initialize the return value, which is a reference.
